# Unexpected error from /172.18.0.1; closing connection (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, logstash, apache-zookeeper

I created a docker-compose for raising 10 conainers aimed for log porpuses and they are working as expected but both kafka and zookeeper continers keep poping up warns and execptions. The containers stack is: local volume with log files -> Filebeat -> Kafka/Zookeeper balanced ( 3 Kafka and 3 Zookeeper containers) -> LogStash - > ElasticSearch -> Kibana.

It is working as expected: if I paste new file in my local volume or add new log lines in current file I can see the result in Kibana.

Nevertheless, I keep getting the error mentioned in this question topic. Today I am running everything in my laptop since this is just a POC but from now on I have to split this Docker Compose in some docker files according to each OpenShift VM I will deploy each container. I want to understand/fix such messages (whole logs and files pasted bellow) before promoting to next level.

I found this discussion [(issues with SSL)](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/issues/1680) a bit close to mine pointing the cause as an SSL issue. Well, as fair as I can see, I am not using SSL at all although I will problem evolve for some SSL demand when I move to production.

So my question is: why I am getting ZOOKEEPER message "...Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.IOException: Len error 1212498244..." and KAFKA message "... Unexpected error from /172.18.0.1; closing connection (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)..." and I still see all connections working properly?

If want to reproduce the environment here is the github with all yml files: [all files](https://github.com/jimisdrpc/DockerComposeLogs)

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.5.2
    volumes:
      - "./kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml"
    restart: always
    environment:
    - SERVER_NAME=kibana.localhost
    - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.5.2
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - xpack.watcher.enabled=false
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - "./esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.5.2
    volumes:
      - "./logstash.conf:/config-dir/logstash.conf"
    restart: always
    command: logstash -f /config-dir/logstash.conf
    ports:
      - "9600:9600"
      - "7777:7777"
    links:
      - elasticsearch
      - kafka1
      - kafka2
      - kafka3
  kafka1:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    command: [start-kafka.sh]
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3
    links:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka1:9092
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_HOURS: "168"
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_BYTES: "100000000"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT:  zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "log:3:3"
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
  kafka2:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3
    links:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3
    ports:
      - "9093:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka2:9092
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_HOURS: "168"
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_BYTES: "100000000"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT:  zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "log:3:3"
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
  kafka3:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3
    links:
      - zoo1
      - zoo2
      - zoo3
    ports:
      - "9094:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka3:9092
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 3
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_HOURS: "168"
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_BYTES: "100000000"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT:  zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "log:3:3"
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
  zoo1:
    image: elevy/zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      MYID: 1
      SERVERS: zoo1,zoo2,zoo3
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  zoo2:
    image: elevy/zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      MYID: 2
      SERVERS: zoo1,zoo2,zoo3
    ports:
      - "2182:2181"
  zoo3:
    image: elevy/zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      MYID: 3
      SERVERS: zoo1,zoo2,zoo3
    ports:
      - "2183:2181"
  filebeat:
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.5.2
    volumes:
      - "./filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml:ro"
      - "./sample-logs:/sample-logs"
    links:
      - kafka1
      - kafka2
      - kafka3
    depends_on:
      - kafka1
      - kafka2
      - kafka3
```

logstash.conf

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "kafka1:9092,kafka2:9092,kafka3:9092"
    client_id => "logstash"
    group_id => "logstash"
    consumer_threads => 3
    topics => ["log"]
    codec => "json"
    tags => ["log", "kafka_source"]
    type => "log"
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "request-sample" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{COMMONAPACHELOG}" }
    }
    date {
      match => ["timestamp", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z"]
      remove_field => ["timestamp"]
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
       hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
       index => "logstash-%{[type]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Kookeeper 1 (same logs in all there Zoo containers)

```
2020-02-13 16:37:13,202 [myid:1] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1044] - Closed socket connection for client /172.18.0.1:35522 (no session established for client)
2020-02-13 16:37:13,553 [myid:1] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@192] - Accepted socket connection from /172.18.0.1:35546
2020-02-13 16:37:13,555 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@373] - Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.IOException: Len error 1212498244
2020-02-13 16:37:13,556 [myid:1] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1044] - Closed socket connection for client /172.18.0.1:35546 (no session established for client)

.....

2020-02-13 16:38:00,988 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@373] - Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.IOException: Len error 1212498244
2020-02-13 16:38:00,988 [myid:1] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1044] - Closed socket connection for client /172.18.0.1:36722 (no session established for client)
2020-02-13 16:38:01,783 [myid:1] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@192] - Accepted socket connection from /172.18.0.1:36730
2020-02-13 16:38:01,786 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@373] - Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.IOException: Len error 1212498244
2020-02-13 16:38:01,787 [myid:1] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1044] - Closed socket connection for client /172.18.0.1:36730 (no session established for client)
```

Kafka 1 (same message in all three Kafka containers)

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2020-02-13 16:35:45,777] WARN [SocketServer brokerId=1] Unexpected error from /172.18.0.1; closing connection (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
org.apache.kafka.common.network.InvalidReceiveException: Invalid receive (size = 1212498244 larger than 104857600)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:424)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:385)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:651)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:572)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:483)
    at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:890)
    at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:789)
[2020-02-13 16:35:46,794] WARN [SocketServer brokerId=1] Unexpected error from /172.18.0.1; closing connection (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2020-02-13 16:35:47,822] WARN [SocketServer brokerId=1] Unexpected error from /172.18.0.1; closing connection (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2020-02-13 16:35:53,296] WARN [SocketServer brokerId=1] Unexpected error from /172.18.0.1; closing connection (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2020-02-13 16:35:54,350] WARN [SocketServer brokerId
...
```

Comment: Why do you need 3 brokers and ZKs? Why do you need logstash? Please show a [mcve]

Comment: 1. Why 3? We will use it foryy all logs of our company and there might happen some unpredictable picks. So I reached the conclusion that I need balanced them. But, please, I am opened for critics. 2. Regard logstash what you see above is really a simple configuration but I will increase significcantly the filter  configuration. I may even have different logstash according to log sources but it is to early to say. 3. Regard minimal reproducible example, have you try clone my github and run it? BTW, do you see any candicate configuration for causing the above error?

Comment: You wouldn't run 3 brokers on one machine, therefore you wouldn't be using Docker Compose to test such an installation. 1 broker and 1 zk can be used for PoC purposes. I'm not going to clone your github, as questions and issues here should be self-contained. Regarding logstash, Kafka Connect Elasticsearch works as well. `172.18.0.1` is a Docker network IP, so some configuration within Docker or your `KAFKA_LISTENERS` variable is messed up (for example, those should all be `PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092`)